# NestJS Injecting request or execution context in services

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

How can I inject the request or the execution context in a service?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since version 6.0, current request can be injected into a service, with `REQUEST` token :

```js
export class AppService {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private request) {}

  load() {
    const user = this.request.user;
  }
}
```

Comment: What about execution context?

Comment: From where I need to import this REQUEST?

Comment: Got it:
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';